# distance to sheared right circular frustum

Tags: geometry, transformation, conic-sections

How do I calculate the distance to a sheared right-circular frustum?

In particular, I'm shearing in a direction perpendicular to the axis, so the cross sections remain parallel circles.

I know I can find the distance from a point to a right-circular cone by looking in the plane defined by two points on the axis and the point I want to measure from... the cone intersects that plane in a triangle, and the distance in 3-space is the distance in the plane from the point to the triangle.